# React native : when to use arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, arrow-functions

I hope nobody gives a bad rating to my question because maybe it seems dumb , but I just want to know the difference in these 2 examples please

***Example 1 :*** what's the difference between `setMyArray(myArray=>[...myArray,objA])` and `setMyArray([...myArray,objA])`

***Example2:*** what's the difference between `<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>functionA()}>` and `<TouchableOpacity onPress={functionA()}>`

**Please make your explanation as simple as possible.**

Comment: one is returning a function and the other one the result of `functionA`?... at most you can ask for the difference between `onPress={()=>functionA()}` and `onPress={functionA}` and with this being said, tray adding a parameter to `functionA` and you will see why they are doing this (so that all the functions you assign has 0 parameters)

Answer (score 0):

For the example 1:

I think you are refering to a useState with setMyArray

```
const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState();

// for manipulating the current value the good practice its because you access to the current value of you array through parameter of that arrow function instead of manipulated it directly like setMyArray([...myArray,objA])
setMyArray(oldStateArray=>[...oldStateArray,objA])
```

Second example
Never use arrow function directly to pass a function in react it re-generate all time if you it like that. Also never pass like onPressButton() you are executing it instead of passing it.
Also call functionA when it need parameter.

```
const onPressButton = () => {
// what ever
functionA(args1, args2...);
}
```